# How do I configure juju for local usage?

Tags: juju, lxc

I'm too cheap to pay for EC2, and I don't have enough servers to set up my own openstack, how do I configure juju to use Linux Containers (LXC) on something like my laptop?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

### Install Juju:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:juju/devel
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install juju-core lxd
```

You just need to configure the local provider:

```
newgrp lxd
```

Then bootstrap a new controller:

```
juju bootstrap lxd-test lxd
```

Follow the documentation for the  rest of the configuration steps:

- [Documentation](https://jujucharms.com/docs/stable/clouds-LXD)

Comment: I'd like to add that for people with more than one environment setup in the yaml file, you select the environment by passing -e <environment_name> to select which one to use.

Comment: After running `juju init -w`, I get an error: " invalid choice: 'init'". I am using the version of Juju in the Raring archives. Do I need to use the PPA?

Comment: I'm using ubuntu 12.04 and I had to add `cloud-archive:tools` PPA in order to be able to bootstrap.

Comment: The documentation link is dead, I found it here instead: https://jaas.ai/docs/lxd-cloud