# When running locally, does Juju use the host machine's APT cache?

Tags: cache, juju

When [juju](http://packages.ubuntu.com/juju) [image: Install juju] fetches packages for a unit, does it make use of the host system's APT cache? I'm asking this because in my case, bandwidth is limited and I am doing some charm development.

It is not really an option to have Juju continuously fetching packages every time I want to test a charm. Is there some way of having Juju cache the packages it fetches so that it doesn't have to download them all each time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using [juju locally](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65359/how-do-i-configure-juju-for-local-usage) then it automatically caches debs using `squid-deb-proxy`.

Juju has an option to allow you to use other apt proxies on your network, see:

- https://juju.ubuntu.com/docs/howto-proxies.html

You basically define it in your `~/.juju/environments.yaml` for the specific environment, like so:

```
apt-http-proxy: http://10.0.3.1:8000
```

Comment: Great, thanks! After the first couple of deploys, I noticed decreased network usage so I assumed something was up :)