# "Failed to start network default" error when trying to juju bootstrap an LXC environment

Tags: juju, debootstrap

```
one@onezero:~/juju$ juju bootstrap
2012-02-13 07:32:26,586 INFO Bootstrapping environment 'sample' (type: local)...
2012-02-13 07:32:26,587 INFO Checking for required packages...
2012-02-13 07:32:26,981 INFO Starting networking...
error: Failed to start network default
error: internal error Network is already in use by interface virbr0

Command '['virsh', 'net-start', 'default']' returned non-zero exit status 1
2012-02-13 07:32:27,248 ERROR Command '['virsh', 'net-start', 'default']' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

with sudo

```
one@onezero:~/juju$ sudo juju bootstrap
2012-02-13 07:34:18,504 INFO Bootstrapping environment 'sample' (type: local)...
2012-02-13 07:34:18,504 INFO Checking for required packages...
2012-02-13 07:34:18,894 INFO Starting networking...
2012-02-13 07:34:18,931 INFO Starting zookeeper...
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/etc/zookeeper/conf/environment'
2012-02-13 07:34:18,932 ERROR [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/etc/zookeeper/conf/environment'
```

how do i fix this error ?

Comment: So which should it be - with sudo or without?  I don't see sudo in the [User tutorial — juju v1.0dev documentation](https://juju.ubuntu.com/docs/user-tutorial.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This happens because you're likely not a member of the `libvirtd`
>   group. You can confirm this by running groups in the command-line. If
>   libvirtd isn't in that list you'll need to do the following:
>
> ```
> sudo usermod -a -G libvirtd <YOUR_USER>
> ```
>
> Once you've added yourself to the group you can either log out/back in
>   or just run:
>
> ```
> newgrp libvirtd
> ```
>
> This will set up that terminal session (and you user for that terminal
>   session) to be a part of the libvirtd group. From here you should be
>   able to run juju bootstrap.

- [How do I configure juju for local usage?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65359/how-do-i-configure-juju-for-local-usage)

Comment: I have zookeeper installed, I've had an rsa key for a long time, and I've rebooted after installing libvirt.  But I still get the same `Network is already in use by interface virbr0` error unless I use sudo: `sudo juju bootstrap`.  But I don't see you using sudo here, nor do I see it in the juju tutorial.  Should that be fixed?

Comment: I don't think that sudo should be used, and I have also the same error even after performing the mentionned steps. So what is the solution?