# Can I use Juju for a single Server or do I need to work in a cloud

Tags: server, juju

Can I use Juju on a single home server using Ubuntu Server 12.04 or do I have to be in a cloud environment to work with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this answer on the JuJu FAQ page that talks about your question:

> Does juju only deploy to the Amazon EC2 cloud?
>
> No. juju can deploy to EC2, OpenStack, and bare metal (MAAS) via LXC
>   containers or Orchestra . When using LXC you are able to run juju
>   charms on a single local machine. This is the recommended method for
>   prototyping charms as it’s quicker to iterate locally and then deploy
>   on the cloud when you’re ready to test.

Source: https://juju.ubuntu.com/FAQ

I believe the LXC  part is something you would be interesting since they recommend it for prototyping charms.

- [How do I configure juju for local usage?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65359/how-do-i-configure-juju-for-local-usage)