# How do I fix a "User timeout caused connection failure" error?

Tags: juju

I'm following these instructions - [How do I configure juju for local usage?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65359/how-do-i-configure-juju-for-local-usage) and all appears well until :

`juju deploy mysql` - which gives

```
2012-08-01 16:14:58,560 INFO Searching for charm cs:precise/mysql in charm store
User timeout caused connection failure.
2012-08-01 16:15:28,592 ERROR User timeout caused connection failure.
```

`~/juju/samples/charms/` is empty.

juju bootstrap completed within 10 secs which I suspect is not correct

```
geme@GEME1:~$ juju bootstrap
2012-08-01 16:13:11,878 INFO Bootstrapping environment 'sample' (origin: distro type: local)...
2012-08-01 16:13:11,880 INFO Checking for required packages...
2012-08-01 16:13:12,525 INFO Starting networking...
2012-08-01 16:13:12,870 INFO Starting zookeeper...
2012-08-01 16:13:13,041 INFO Starting storage server...
2012-08-01 16:13:15,474 INFO Initializing zookeeper hierarchy
2012-08-01 16:13:17,846 INFO Starting machine agent (origin: distro)... 
2012-08-01 16:13:19,483 INFO Environment bootstrapped
2012-08-01 16:13:19,487 INFO 'bootstrap' command finished successfully
```

status shows :

```
geme@GEME1:~$ juju status
machines:
  0:
    agent-state: running
    dns-name: localhost
    instance-id: local
    instance-state: running
services: {}
2012-08-01 16:13:28,304 INFO 'status' command finished successfully
geme@GEME1:~$ juju -v status
2012-08-01 16:13:44,419 DEBUG Initializing juju status runtime
2012-08-01 16:13:44,522:2807(0xb77abb00):ZOO_INFO@log_env@658: Client environment:zookeeper.version=zookeeper C client 3.3.5
2012-08-01 16:13:44,522:2807(0xb77abb00):ZOO_INFO@log_env@662: Client environment:host.name=GEME1
2012-08-01 16:13:44,523:2807(0xb77abb00):ZOO_INFO@log_env@669: Client environment:os.name=Linux
2012-08-01 16:13:44,523:2807(0xb77abb00):ZOO_INFO@log_env@670: Client environment:os.arch=3.2.0-23-generic-pae
2012-08-01 16:13:44,523:2807(0xb77abb00):ZOO_INFO@log_env@671: Client environment:os.version=#36-Ubuntu SMP Tue Apr 10 22:19:09 UTC 2012
2012-08-01 16:13:44,532:2807(0xb77abb00):ZOO_INFO@log_env@679: Client environment:user.name=geme
2012-08-01 16:13:44,535:2807(0xb77abb00):ZOO_INFO@log_env@687: Client environment:user.home=/home/geme
2012-08-01 16:13:44,535:2807(0xb77abb00):ZOO_INFO@log_env@699: Client environment:user.dir=/home/geme
2012-08-01 16:13:44,535:2807(0xb77abb00):ZOO_INFO@zookeeper_init@727: Initiating client connection, host=192.168.122.1:59761 sessionTimeout=10000 watcher=0xd9f620 sessionId=0 sessionPasswd=<null> context=0x8a43440 flags=0
2012-08-01 16:13:44,545:2807(0xb7483b40):ZOO_INFO@check_events@1585: initiated connection to server [192.168.122.1:59761]
2012-08-01 16:13:44,564:2807(0xb7483b40):ZOO_INFO@check_events@1632: session establishment complete on server [192.168.122.1:59761], sessionId=0x138e2bf765f0003, negotiated timeout=10000
2012-08-01 16:13:44,573 DEBUG Environment is initialized.
machines:
  0:
    agent-state: running
    dns-name: localhost
    instance-id: local
    instance-state: running
services: {}
2012-08-01 16:13:44,599 INFO 'status' command finished successfully
```

With verbose flag:

```
juju -vv deploy mysql
2012-08-02 17:37:52,895 DEBUG Initializing juju deploy runtime
2012-08-02 17:37:52,897 INFO Searching for charm cs:precise/mysql in charm store
Traceback (most recent call last):<br>
Failure: twisted.internet.error.TimeoutError: User timeout caused connection failure.
2012-08-02 17:38:22,936 ERROR Traceback (most recent call last):
Failure: twisted.internet.error.TimeoutError: User timeout caused connection failure.

User timeout caused connection failure.
2012-08-02 17:38:22,942 ERROR User timeout caused connection failure.
```

Comment: It's normal for juju bootstrap to complete quickly. It launches a background process, that's what takes a long time. Just a comment though, based on my experience; I can't help further than that :(

Comment: I might have been a bit impatient but its now over an hout since I started juju bootstrap. I can see some background python processes running but still nothing in ~/juju other than charms/ files/ state/ units/ zookeeper.

Answer (score 1):

The bootstrapping quickly is to be expected. In most environments the bootstrap will actually spin up a machine, when you're working with a local deployment it just creates the first LXC container and sets up networking. So this typically takes 10-20 seconds. The magic happens on the first deployment, as explained in [this local configuration question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65359/how-do-i-configure-juju-for-local-usage), this is when Juju downloads ~300MB server image and creates the "master container" which all future deployments are based on.

Now, the error your receiving appears to state that there's a timeout trying to reach the Juju Charm store. I wasn't aware of any outages, but it might be because you're behind a proxy or some other kind of networking issue/timeout. I'd recommend trying again (`juju destroy-environment -e local`) then re-bootstrap.

If you're having proxy issues, you can download charms locally using Bazaar:

```
mkdir -p ~/charms/precise
cd ~/charms/precise
bzr branch lp:charms/mysql
juju deploy --repository=~/charms local:mysql
```

While the directory can be anything, the important item to follow is each charm needs to be in a series folder (following the Ubuntu release names). Outside of that you use `--repository` which instructs Juju to search *here* for charms, and the `local:` prefix tells Juju that the deployment will be from that local `--repository` path.

Comment: I think it's because of the network proxy. This looks similiar - https://bugs.launchpad.net/charms/+bug/1028099

Comment: It really seems like a proxy a duplicate of that bug unfortunately. I'm not sure of a solution at this time though/

Comment: Is there way I can download the charms into a local repository and deploy from these ?

Comment: Yes, you can. If bzr still works for you, you can just `bzr branch lp:charms/mysql`. I'll update my answer

Comment: Great that works. Charm deploys though state is stuck "pendind" but that's another question. I have very little experience with python - but it seems that common proxy envars ( http_proxy, https_proxy ) are not supported - so will I see further juju connectivity problems ?