# Can I use juju with LXC in a non-local configuration?

Tags: juju, lxc

I've looked at [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65359/how-do-i-configure-juju-for-local-usage) for setting up juju on a local environment with lxc. However, is there a way to use juju with lxc in a non-local environment?

I am looking at a scenario where lxc containers are deployed on multiple nodes. I.e., lets say I have virtual machines m1 and m2 with wordpress deployed on a container in m1 and mysql deployed on a container in m2. Is there a way to orchestrate these deployments with juju?

Answer (score 2):

Currently the LXC container provider is meant to be used on your local machine, like your laptop.

There currently is no way to do what you want with Juju and LXC, though it's a nice idea. I recommend filing a feature request bug on juju:

- [How do I report a bug?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug)