# juju bootstrap: "ERROR SSH authorized/public key not found"

Tags: ssh, juju

I installed Ubuntu Server 12.10 in a VM and tried to setup Juju following these guides:

https://juju.ubuntu.com/get-started/

https://juju.ubuntu.com/docs/getting-started.html#configuring-a-local-environment

[How do I configure juju for local usage?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65359/how-do-i-configure-juju-for-local-usage)

I'll put here the exact commands I used.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:juju/pkgs
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install juju
sudo apt-get install lxc apt-cacher-ng libzookeeper-java zookeeper
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 2048
juju bootstrap
nano .juju/environments.yaml
mkdir whatever
juju bootstrap
```

enviroments.yaml after edited:

```
environments:
  sample:
    type: local
    control-bucket: juju-831d06b0c3c94d4d816f0b70c37460ea
    admin-secret: 353b2c52ba144dd5b22dffbf8c69c833
    default-series: precise
    ssl-hostname-verification: true
    data-dir: /home/victor/whatever
```

When I run "juju bootstrap" I get this error:

```
2013-02-14 23:05:00,846 INFO Bootstrapping environment 'sample' (origin: distro type: local)...
2013-02-14 23:05:00,847 INFO Checking for required packages...
2013-02-14 23:05:01,408 ERROR SSH authorized/public key not found.
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: When I generated public/private rsa key pair, I press 'y' instead of 'Enter'. The keys were created under $PWD instead of .ssh, so I got the same error. What is your `ls ~/.ssh/` output?

Answer (score 1):

Check to make sure that you didn't create it as root, because this way the .ssh directory will be placed in the /root directory. I made this mistake, but after copying the .ssh dir for /root to my default user directory, it worked perfectly.