# juju local openstack deploy - how to reduce the memory/number of lxc containers?

Tags: juju, openstack, vagrant

I'm trying to setup openstack with vagrant inside a virtualbox guest, by following the juju instructions in the ubuntu cloud infrastructure [wiki page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuCloudInfrastructure#Deploying_Ubuntu_Cloud_Infrastructure_with_Juju) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65359/how-do-i-configure-juju-for-local-usage) askubuntu page.

My github project is [here](https://github.com/snowch/stratos-vagrant-runtime).

My provision scripts run without error [see edit], but eventually the guest grinds to a halt because a large number of lxc containers are created and memory is exhausted.

On the ubuntu [wiki page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuCloudInfrastructure#Deploying_Ubuntu_Cloud_Infrastructure_with_Juju), there are some instructions for reducing the number of lxc containers by deploying some services together:

```
jitsu deploy-to [machine # of keystone] glance
jitsu deploy-to [machine # of mysql] rabbitmq-server
jitsu deploy-to [machine # of keystone] openstack-dashboard
```

However, there are still quite a few lxc containers.

**Question 1**: Will deploying to fewer containers require significantly less memory?

**Question 2**: Is it possible to host all openstack services in a single lxc container?

**Question 3**: What is the minimum memory I need to deploy openstack?  I'm only looking to create a demo environment for openstack so usage will be very low.

**Question 4**: Is there a different way that I can reduce the guest memory requirements?

---

EDIT:

`juju status` reports the following errors for nova-compute and nova-volume:

```
  nova-compute:
    charm: cs:precise/nova-compute-18
    exposed: false
    relations:
      amqp:
      - rabbitmq-server
      cloud-compute:
      - nova-cloud-controller
      compute-peer:
      - nova-compute
      image-service:
      - glance
      shared-db:
      - mysql
    units:
      nova-compute/0:
        agent-state: error
        agent-state-info: 'hook failed: "install"'
        agent-version: 1.16.5.1
        machine: "6"
        public-address: 10.0.3.24
  nova-volume:
    charm: cs:precise/nova-volume-6
    exposed: false
    relations:
      amqp:
      - rabbitmq-server
      nova-volume-service:
      - nova-cloud-controller
      shared-db:
      - mysql
    units:
      nova-volume/0:
        agent-state: error
        agent-state-info: 'hook failed: "install"'
        agent-version: 1.16.5.1
        machine: "5"
        public-address: 10.0.3.240
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use jitsu to deploy to specific machines.

```
juju help deploy
```

shows how to use the `--to` placement directive

Now to try to answer your other questions:

> Question 1: Will deploying to fewer containers require significantly less memory?

Yes.

> Question 2: Is it possible to host all openstack services in a single lxc container?

No I don't think so. The compute units I believe don't like being inside LXC themselves.

Also I think that the storage components don't like being in LXC containers either as they need access to the block device.

> Question 3: What is the minimum memory I need to deploy openstack? I'm only looking to create a demo environment for openstack so usage will be very low.

Not sure.

> Question 4: Is there a different way that I can reduce the guest memory requirements?

No, I think this is the best way.